# Who is the other servant, Israel of God?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 49:3

> He said to Me, "You are My Servant, Israel, In Whom I will show My
>   glory."

Isaiah 42:19-20

> Who is blind but My servant, Or so deaf as My messenger whom I send?
>   Who is so blind as he that is at peace with Me, Or so blind as the
>   servant of the Lord? You have seen many things, but you do not observe
>   them; Your ears are open, but none hears.

Isaiah 41:25

> "I have aroused one from the north, and he has come; From the rising
>   of the sun he will call on My name; And he will come upon rulers as
>   upon mortar, Even as the potter treads clay.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Please [edit] this to explain what your question is. Quoting various verses out of order isn't enough for us to understand what you're thinking.

Comment: Ruminator, I reverted your edit because it changed too much without clear indication that the author meant this. There is no indication that the author is interested in this text as a messianic prophecy or that Isa. 41:25 is at the core of their question rather than the other two verses. Like curiousdannii, I would very much appreciate clarification from the original author themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Isaiah 41-42 is following a theme where God rebukes Israel for their idolatry, and shows Himself as the one true God. The servant mentioned in those chapters will be Jesus Christ, the true God and not a idol.

Isaiah 49 also talks about the coming of the Messiah, Jesus Christ, as a servant of God in His role as a Son to the Father. He is aptly called "Israel" because the name means Ruled by God.

Comment: But He will aroused ONE from the north,from the rising of the sun, is the  ONE there the true messenger of God?